# How to kill nodemon process on mac?

Tags: node.js, macos, shell, oh-my-zsh, nodemon

I am having trouble with exiting past nodemon instance.

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    98355 user   14u  IPv6 0x51b8b9857a4e56a3      0t0  TCP *:redwood-broker (LISTEN)
```

It has taken my 3000 port so I am trying to exit it. I searched it by using `lsof -wni tcp:3000`

I could see that PID is 98335, so tried `kill 98335`, `kill -9 98335`, `sudo kill 98335`, `sudo kill -9 98335` and so on but no luck, it's just saying

```
kill: kill 98335 failed: no such process
```

But if I save something, nodemon watching job is printing out to console, which means that process is still alive.

Please help me.

Comment: PID is 98355 - you want to kill 98335 (check number an position of 3s and 5s)

Answer (score 29):

https://github.com/remy/nodemon/issues/1386

To work around the issue, **find the proces running on the port number** and kill it:

```
 kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:3000)
```

**OR**

Install **1.17.5** `npm install nodemon@1.17.5 --save-dev --save-exact`.

Comment: yay. this question returned for searching how to kill a node process without process.title. (since process.title doesn't work... anywhere).

Answer (score 13):

you can use

```
ps -ef | grep node
```

to find the process id

and then

```
sudo kill -9 <PID>
```

PID is the process ID. Try the following command in terminal to list and search for process using a regex:-

```
ps gx | grep 'Symantec'
```

The above example is to list all the 'Symantec' related processes. Replace 'Symantec' with your own phrase. Next use variations of 'kill' command. You can either use:-

```
kill pid
```

Replace 'pid' with actual process id. Or use,

```
killall
```

as suggested before. To reiterate another useful suggestion, use

```
man kill
```

to see the manual for 'kill' command and also scroll down and see related commands which is mentioned under.

Comment: This should be downvoted into the negatives, because the person who answered clearly doesn't realize that nodemon is something that respawns the instance after it's killed. A general "what does 'kill' do" answer does not apply.

Answer (score 2):

to kill all running node processes with -9 option

```
sudo pkill -f node -9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```

This will forcefully kill your process

Comment: @BarakShirali, how did you started this process? on terminal ? if yes then press ctrl+c,, it will be stopped.

Comment: ctrl+c didn't quit it fully unfortunately. If I save a file, nodemon instance restarts again

Answer (score -1):

you kill wrong PID its 98355 not 98335

Comment: PID depends on your env. each process has it's own ID. These numbers are valid only for the running process while it's running. Even on same machine re-run same thing and it may have different PID each time. Learn more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier